# How to Fix Misplaced When Stamp Image on Setasign SetaPDF_Stamper_Image

Tags: php, pdf, setapdf

With SetaPdf_Stamper from Setasign, when i importing certain document and trying to stamp image to some page. The position of image is wrong. The position of image must be in the upper left corner, when i set position:

```
SetaPDF_Stamper::POSITION_LEFT_TOP, 'translateX' => 0,   'translateY' => 0
```

I've read manual from setasign. I get some clue like as give `$page->getStreamProxy()->encapsulateExistingContentInGraphicState();`. but still it does'nt work.

```
$document = SetaPDF_Core_Document::loadByFilename(
    'oprek.pdf', $writer
);
$stamp = new SetaPDF_Stamper_Stamp_Image(SetaPDF_Core_Image::getByPath('arrow-annotation.png'));
$pages = $document->getCatalog()->getPages();
$page = $pages->getPage(1);
$stamp->setWidth(80);
$stamp->setHeight(40);
$stamper = new SetaPDF_Stamper($document);
$page->getStreamProxy()->encapsulateExistingContentInGraphicState();
$stamper->addStamp(
    $stamp,
    array(
        'position' => SetaPDF_Stamper::POSITION_LEFT_TOP,
        'showOnPage' => 1,
        'translateX' => 0,
        'translateY' => 0,
        'rotation' => 90
    )
);
$stamper->stamp();
```

The result in this image:

[image]

Comment: You don't need to encapsulate anything manually with the Stamper component. This is done under the hood. Actually I assume that the image is simply larger than you expect or the PDF has a faulty boundary box. To answer this could you please add the file `arrow-annotation.png` and `oprek.pdf` to your question? You're also welcome to send them to support@setasign.com if they need to be kept confidential.